# Magento 1 is not creating database tables when re-installing it

Tags: install-script

I did a test deleting catalogrule tables from database. I've made the preparation for re-installing Magento script. The installation process went smooth. Checking the database catalogrule tables were not created.

What is actually doing re-installation of Magento?

Comment: Remove entires from `core_resource` table for that module too

Comment: Check for the `sql setup` name basically a folder name under `module/sql`. Find that and remove that entry and try again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove respective entries from `core_resource` table. Please do that and try again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing any module that you have tried also earlier..then you have to look for that module name entry in the core_resource table.

Delete those entries. and look for that module SQL install file. Maybe it can overwrite any of existing table of Magento and create some more table in existing tables. So you need to remove those extra fields carefully before proceeding installation again.

Hope this helps you to proceed for further.